# Best way to calculate a calculated property - Linq or foreach loop?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, foreach

My code in fact is working, tested in three different ways, but I'm interested in knowing if what is the best way of achieving it.

Have a Vehicle.cs class with a collection, and want to calculate the average consumption of all the entries.

This works:

```
public ICollection<FuelingEntry> FuelingEntries { get; set; }

public double TotalAverageConsumption
{
    get
    {
        double fuelingEntriesQuantitySum = 0;
        double fuelingEntriesTripOdometerSum = 0;

        foreach (var fuelingEntry in FuelingEntries)
        {
            fuelingEntriesQuantitySum += fuelingEntry.Quantity;
            fuelingEntriesTripOdometerSum += fuelingEntry.TripOdometer;
        }

        return (fuelingEntriesQuantitySum / fuelingEntriesTripOdometerSum) * 100;
    }
}
```

And with "basic" LINQ too:

```
public ICollection<FuelingEntry> FuelingEntries { get; set; }

public double TotalAverageConsumption
{
    get
    {
        var fuelingEntriesQuantitySum = (from f in FuelingEntries select f.Quantity).Sum();
        var fuelingEntriesTripOdometerSum = (from f in FuelingEntries select f.TripOdometer).Sum();

        // var fuelingEntriesQuantitySum = FuelingEntries.Select(f => f.Quantity).Sum();
        // var fuelingEntriesTripOdometerSum = FuelingEntries.Select(f => f.TripOdometer).Sum();

        return (fuelingEntriesQuantitySum / fuelingEntriesTripOdometerSum) * 100;
    }
}
```

Which is the best way or there is another?

Comment: The LINQ version is two loops vs one for `foreach`. However, the LINQ version can be reduced to one statement, but whatever you do, it's more a matter of preference.

Comment: use profiler in the Visual Studio, you can have a better understanding of what should be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

As written the first option with the `foreach` loop is more efficient as you only have to loop through the collection once, your linq version loops through twice. Both approaches are going to be prone to failure or odd results if it is possible to update the collection or the collection items whilst you are accessing the property.